# Multivariate copula estimation

Tags: correlation, copula, spearman-rho

Multivariate copulas are oftentimes used for financial modeling. A copula can be constructing by tying together a series of marginal distributions, with a dependency structure. In case of a t-copula, this dependency structure could be a correlation matrix.

Consider the following system of three assets:

```
A = t
B = A + sin(A)
C = A - sin(A)
```

This system will produce an unconditional spearmans correlation matrix of (in terms of positive or negative correlations):

```
_ A B C
A 1 + +
B + 1 +
C + + 1
```

while the **partial** correlations are

```
_ A B C
A 1 + +
B + 1 -
C + - 1
```

Using the unconditional spearmans correlation could indicate that two variables are positively correlated, when they in fact - when cleansing for outside effects - are negatively correlated. Can this be an issue when defining the dependency of a copula through unconditional correlations?

Comment: I don't follow this question because (1) it is not true that copulas are defined through correlation matrices (that is kind of the whole point of copulas: they are far more general) and (2) the statement of the question in the last sentence is garbled and almost unintelligible--perhaps some typographical errors crept in?

Comment: I'm so sorry - just edited it, hopefully the question is clearer now.